# How to structure conditional hooks in FeathersJS?

Tags: feathersjs

I've been reading through the documentation, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm trying to implement a custom conditional hook by wrapping some supplied hooks. It should restrict access to a service (the method doesn't matter) by:

1) First checking if the user has the `admin` or `super-admin` roles using:

```
auth.restrictToRoles({
  roles: ['admin', 'super-admin']
}),
```

If the user has the required roles, the hook should allow access. Otherwise..

2) Restrict access to owner using:

```
auth.restrictToOwner({ ownerField: 'id' }),
```

What I can't figure out is how to get and check the result of `auth.restrictToRoles` so I can run `auth.restrictToOwner` if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are two options. The easier on is to not use the pre-built hooks. Almost every pre-built hook can be implemented on your own in just a couple of lines of code. It could look like this:

```
app.service('myservice').before({
  find(hook) {
    const { user } = hook.params;
    const {roles } = user;

    if(roles.indexOf('admin') !== -1 && roles.indexOf('super-admin') !== -1) {
      hook.params.query.userId = user._id;
    }
  }  
});
```

The other way would be to create a wrapper hook that first calls restrictToRoles and then `catches` any error (notice that it is basically more code than implementing it entirely on your own):

```
const restrictToRoles = auth.restrictToRoles({
  roles: ['admin', 'super-admin']
});
const restrictToOwner = auth.restrictToOwner({ ownerField: 'id' });

app.service('myservice').before({
  find(hook) {
    return restrictToRoles(hook).catch(() => restrictToOwner(hook));
  }  
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I ended up going with a kind of combination of the two, and its working well.